# set unique values to lookup edit data source

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I'm trying to put non duplicated values in a lookup edit using the code below but the variable `unique` is always `null`, and I don't know where is the problem.

Any help please?

```
List<VueItemItemUnit> liste = ObjReservation.LoadAllFamilles();
var unique =
      from element in liste
      group element by element.FA_CODE into Group
      where Group.Count() == 1
      select Group.Key;

lookUpFamille.Properties.DataSource = unique;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var unique = liste.Distinct(element => element.FA_CODE).Select(element => element.FA_CODE);
```

Comment: Add a `ToList()` if nedded.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the following approach:

```
lookUpFamille.Properties.DataSource = list.DistinctBy(e => e.FA_CODE).ToList();
//...
// DistinctBy<T,TKey> extension
static class EnumerableHelper {
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector) {
        return source.Distinct(new EqualityComparer<T, TKey>(keySelector));
    }
    class EqualityComparer<T, TKey> : IEqualityComparer<T> {
        readonly Func<T, TKey> keySelector;
        public EqualityComparer(Func<T, TKey> keySelector) {
            this.keySelector = keySelector;
        }
        bool IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals(T x, T y) {
            return Equals(keySelector(x), keySelector(y));
        }
        int IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode(T obj) {
            return keySelector(obj).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```